# WPF SelectTemplate called multiple times

Tags: wpf, templates

I have a treeview and each time I switch among the nodes, I load a DataTemplate in order to show properly data.
This is an example of by DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="dataFlexBCR" DataType="{x:Type cls:cFlexBcr}">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="grdDataFlexBcr" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Desc" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="vActive" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Modalità indentificazione: " Style="{StaticResource labelStyle2}" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ConfigObject.Bcrs}" Style="{StaticResource popModeStyle}" SelectionChanged="Combo_SelectionChanged" Typography.Capitals="AllPetiteCaps" SelectedValue="{Binding ConfigObject.ActiveId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<local:FlexconfigTemplateSelector dataFlexBCR="{StaticResource dataFlexBCR}" dataFlexBCRs="{StaticResource dataFlexBCRs}" x:Key="flexconfigTemplateSelector" />
```

The problem is that my SelectTemplate method (below) is called for each rows present in the datagrid defined in the template. So if I have 20 rows, the template is called 20 times.

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
    LeafInfo li = item as LeafInfo;

    if (li == null) return null;

    if (li.ConfigObject is cFlexBcrSingle)
        return dataFlexBCR;

    if (li.ConfigObject is cFlexBcr)
        return dataFlexBCRs;

    return null;
}
```

Code behind of my FleconfigTemplateSelector:

```
public class FlexconfigTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate dataFlexBCR { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate dataFlexBCRs { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// template
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    /// <param name="container"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        LeafInfo li = item as LeafInfo;

        if (li == null) return null;

        if (li.ConfigObject is cFlexBcr)
            return dataFlexBCRs;

        if (li.ConfigObject is cFlexBcrSingle)
            return dataFlexBCR;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Why this behaviour? Shouldn't the template called once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. The `SelectTemplate` method is called for each item in an `ItemsControl` and the returned `DataTemplate` is then applied to the corresponding object in its `ItemsSource` collection.

It you only want to call it once for all objects, you might as well use an `ItemTemplate`.